# Windows Server 2003 (IIS) - Locating my FTP..

Tags: windows, ftp, iis-6, installation

We have a Windows 2003 Server running IIS6, which was setup long before my time.

Now that I've had a request to set-up an isolated FTP user account for a client (so that they have access to their own website only), I can't actually find what FTP program is being used, and thus I'm unable to set-up their account.

It doesn't appear to be using the FTP system integrated into IIS6, as the FTProot folder that the only and default FTP Site is pointing to is empty. And I've also went through the programs list to no avail.

Is there any way to trace back to find what FTP Application our FTP is set-up on?

Thanks

Comment: Offtopic here. Try on http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise there was a serverfault.com! My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

open up a command prompt and type:

```
ftp ftp.mydomain.com  (replace ftp.mydomain.com with yours)
```

and hit Enter.  What does it say?

Comment: At the moment I get: 220 Microsoft FTP Service

Answer (score 0):

"At the moment I get: 220 Microsoft FTP Service" means it is using IIS.  Maybe it is not on your server.  Use nslookup to see if it is point to your server IP.

Another possibility.  In IIS the FTP service is separate from the WWW service but available in the same snapin.  Look at the properties of the FTP service and note the directory it is point to - may not be the same as the default directory.